# generate every possible permutation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
project_id    member_id
1             A
1             B
1             C
2             A
2             D
2             B
```

I want to find all pairs of people that have worked together on at least one project. So the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
member_id    co_member_id
A            B
A            C
A            D
B            A
B            C
B            D
C            A
C            B
D            A
D            B
```

One way I could think of is to `df.groupby('project_id')` but then I would have to calculate a pairwise permutation of every possible unique value within each `project_id` , then drop any duplicate pairings in the resulting df.

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: So you want a join (in the relational calculus or SQL sense) based on project ID? Also, how is your data frame represented? Are you using any libraries (e.g. [tag:pandas])?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a functional method which does not rely on `pandas`:

```
from itertools import permutations
from collections import defaultdict

project_id = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
member_id = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B']

d = defaultdict(list)

# create dictionary of project -> members
for i, j in zip(project_id, member_id):
    d[i].append(j)

# permute pairs and get union
set.union(*(set(permutations(v, 2)) for v in d.values()))

# {('A', 'B'),
#  ('A', 'C'),
#  ('A', 'D'),
#  ('B', 'A'),
#  ('B', 'C'),
#  ('B', 'D'),
#  ('C', 'A'),
#  ('C', 'B'),
#  ('D', 'A'),
#  ('D', 'B')}
```

Answer (score 2):

A great answer above by jp_data_analysis. However, you are loosing the information about the projects, which may or may not be always desired. The code below returns all the information in three lines without any explicit loops.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create data frame
project_id = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
member_id = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame({'project_id': project_id, 'member_id': member_id})

# New data frame with co_member_id
df1 = pd.merge(df, df, how='inner', on=['project_id'])
df1 = df1[df1['member_id_x'] != df1['member_id_y']]
df1.columns = ['member_id', 'project_id', 'co_member_id']

print(df1)

   member_id  project_id co_member_id
1          A           1            B
2          A           1            C
3          B           1            A
5          B           1            C
6          C           1            A
7          C           1            B
10         A           2            D
11         A           2            B
12         D           2            A
14         D           2            B
15         B           2            A
16         B           2            D
```

A multi-index and groupby gives you a very succinct result:

```
df3 = df1.set_index(['member_id', 'co_member_id'])
df3 = df.groupby('project_id').sum()
print(df3)

           member_id
project_id          
1                ABC
2                ADB
```

Comment: I was blown away by yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
project_id = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
member_id = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B']

import itertools
track={}
combination=[]
for i in zip(project_id,member_id):
    if i[0] not in track:
        track[i[0]]=[i[1]]
    else:
        track[i[0]].append(i[1])

[combination.append(k) for i,j in track.items() for k in itertools.permutations(j,r=2) if k not in combination]


print({m:list(l) for m,l in itertools.groupby(sorted(combination),lambda x:x[0])})
```

output:

```
{'A': [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D')], 'B': [('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D')], 'C': [('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B')], 'D': [('D', 'A'), ('D', 'B')]}
```